# operator "OR" TCL

Tags: tcl, operators

This is not a question associated with TCL , as I know… I write it in this tag. 
 It is possible to know which variable is not correct when I write :

```
set l1 0
set l2 2

if {$l1 == 0 || $l2 == 1} {
    return {your variable $l1 or $l2 is not correct}
}
```

To avoid it I write :

```
if {$l1 == 0} {
    return {your variable $l1 is not correct}
}

if {$l2 == 1} {
    return {your variable $l2 is not correct}
}
```

there is a better solution ?

Answer (score 2):

No.
If you want to know which variable is wrong, you have
to test the specific variable.

You can reduce some duplication of text:

```
set errstr "your variable %s (value %s) is not correct"
if { $l1 == 0 } {
  return [format $errstr l1 $l1]
}
if { $l2 == 1 } {
  return [format $errstr l2 $l2]
}
```

But that's just coding style and really isn't that important.

Comment: ok , thank you both , there is no quick-fix solutions , just coding style if I understand, I edited my code ,simply to highlight the name of my **{2 variables}**

Answer (score 2):

This is another way to do it. Whether it is better is up to you:

```
foreach {name val} {l1 0 l2 1} {
    upvar 0 $name var
    if {$var == $val} {
        return "your variable $name is not correct"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In specific situations, especially when you have a lot of variables and you know exactly the boundaries of the variables (minimum and maximum value of the variables), you can make use of a dictionary and [bitwise `&`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).

The example below will be one where each variable can have 2 possible values (either 0 or 1, it's an example based on how Discord chat permissions are calculated).

```
set permissions {
  perm1   0x00000001
  perm2   0x00000002
  perm3   0x00000004
  perm4   0x00000008
  perm5   0x00000010
  perm6   0x00000020
  perm7   0x00000040
  perm8   0x00000080
}

set permDict [dict create {*}$permissions]

proc getPermList {perms} {
  # Ensure perms is an integer
  if {![string is integer -strict $perms]} {
    return -code error "Not an integer: $perms"
  }
  # This list will contain matched permissions
  set permList [list]
  dict for {permission value} $::permDict {
    if {$perms & $value} {
      lappend permList $permission
    }
  }
  # Return the list
  return $permList
}
```

In the above, each permission has the following values:

```
Perm     Hexadecimal   Binary      Decimal
perm1 -> 0x00000001 -> 00000001 ->   1
perm2 -> 0x00000002 -> 00000010 ->   2
perm3 -> 0x00000004 -> 00000100 ->   4
perm4 -> 0x00000008 -> 00001000 ->   8
perm5 -> 0x00000010 -> 00010000 ->  16
perm6 -> 0x00000020 -> 00100000 ->  32
perm7 -> 0x00000040 -> 01000000 ->  64
perm8 -> 0x00000080 -> 10000000 -> 128
```

And a particular combination of permissions will have the sum of the individual permissions. For example if someone has both perm1 and perm4, their total permissions will be 9. The reverse will use the proc above; i.e. we have the value of 9 and we want to know which permissions that person has. So we would do `getPermList 9` and we get as result: `perm1 perm4`.

In binary, 9 is represented as:

```
00001001
```

And the individual permissions of perm1 and perm4 are as follows:

```
00000001
00001000
```

Adding the two (add the numbers vertically) gives the binary representation of 9. So what's happening here?

The loop (`dict for`) is comparing each value of the dict to the permission we want the detail for:

```
perm1
Binary:  00001001    Decimal:    9
       & 00000001             &  1
       = 00000001             =  1
```

Since the result is greater than 0, perm1 is one of the permissions that is given to the permission with total value of 9.

```
perm2
Binary:  00001001    Decimal:    9
       & 00000010             &  2
       = 00000000             =  0
```

Since the result is 0, perm2 is not one of the permissions that is given to the permission with total value of 9. The loop goes on and we find that the only other time it gives a non-zero result is with perm4:

```
perm4
Binary:  00001001    Decimal:    9
       & 00001000             &  8
       = 00001000             =  8
```

You can read how bitwise & works on the wikipedia link I have at the beginning, but in essence, `1 & 1` gives 1, `1 & 0`, `0 & 1` and `0 & 0` all give 0.

If someone has all the permissions, they would have a permission value of 255 (1+2+4+...+128), and if you do `getPermList 255`, you'll get all the permissions listed in the dictionary.